# SQL How to GROUP BY, DISTINCT, SUM

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm very new to SQL so my apologies for the undoubtedly newb question.I'm doing a college module on SQL.

I have a table that looks like this.

```
ID  Learning Area           Course Name                  Qualification    Level Enrolments
1   Business & Management   Accounting (AAT)              Certificate      Two   20
2   Business & Management   Accounting (AAT)              Diploma          Three 10
3   Business & Management   Accounting (AAT)              Extended Diploma Four  13
4   Health & Childcare  Anatomy, Physiology and Pathology Diploma          Two   19
```

[image]

(Apologies for the picture. I can not work out how to add tables to my questions on here so any help with that would also be greatly appreciated.)

This is the task I've been given:

Unique course names, showing the numbers of letters in each name and the total number of enrolments.

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Course Name], Len([Course Name]) AS Letters, SUM (Enrolments) AS Total_Enrolments
FROM DataFile
GROUP BY [Course Name], Enrolments;
```

However, what I get in return is this.

```
Course Name                       Letters   Total_Enrolments
Accounting (AAT)                      16    10
Accounting (AAT)                      16    13
Accounting (AAT)                      16    20
Anatomy, Physiology and Pathology     33    19
Animal Care                           11    12
```

The "Course Names" are no longer DISTINCT when I add SUM

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aggregating only by the course name:

```
SELECT [Course Name], LEN([Course Name]) AS Letters, SUM (Enrolments) AS Total_Enrolments
FROM DataFile
GROUP BY [Course Name];
```

Note that `DISTINCT` is also redundant and not necessary here, since grouping by the course name already ensures that each course will appear only once in the result set.

Comment: Thank you so much and thanks again for telling about DISTINCT!